# Android wont clear time interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, clearinterval, cleartimeout

I have an issue where on a android device, the ClearInterval command wont work. If i use it on IOS it works a charm! Clears perfectly, but on android it wont clear for me. Why is this? I cant honestly figure it out! I ran some alerts and it is getting into the touchstart, and touchend and the timeout runs perfectly but its the timeinterval that wont get cleared!

My code:

```
var touchticker = null;
var touchtickerint = null;

//TouchStart Volume UP
$("#volumeup").on("touchstart", function() {
    touchticker = setTimeout(function() {
        touchtickerint = setInterval(function() 
        {
            $("#volumeup").click();
        }, 100);
    }, 500);
});

//TouchEnd Clear Timeout
$(document).on("touchend", function() 
{
    clearInterval(touchtickerint);
    clearTimeout(touchticker);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://github.com/TNT-RoX/android-swipe-shim:

> On some Android devices when the user touches the screen a touchstart
>   event is fired, Android passes the event to WebView (javascript) to be
>   handled. If WebView does not preventdefault (within 200ms), Android
>   resumes native scrolling and stops passing touch events to WebView.

The solution to this has mostly been to preventDefault on touchstart and manually scroll using javascript.

```
var touchticker = null,
    touchtickerint = null,
    volumeup = $("#volumeup"),
    isAndroid = /Android/i.test(navigato​r.userAgent);

//TouchStart Volume UP
volumeup.on("touchstart", function(event) {
    if (isAndroid) { event.preventDefault(); volumeup.click(); }
    touchticker = setTimeout(function() {
        clearInterval(touchtickerint);
        touchtickerint = setInterval(function() {
            volumeup.click();
        }, 100);
    }, 500);
});

//TouchEnd Volume UP, Clear Timeout
$(document).on('touchend touchcancel', function() {
    clearInterval(touchtickerint);
    clearTimeout(touchticker);
});
```

Comment: Will give this a go, and will be back with results! Looks promising. So annoying how it works on IOS and not android though, still not sure why that is! Anywho, will be back with results. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to use the full call: window.clearInterval?  Idk if that would help but maybe try it out.

Comment: Will try your updated way but no i honestly forgot to give it a shot! Hopefully this will work. I Appreciate your help!. As for, @Lacrioque Will give that a shot if the above dont work! Thanks:)

Comment: @Annarfych Sadly, now it wont work on IOS. I didnt try Android because i doubt it will work if it wont work on IOS. It doesnt seem to be doing the `$("#volumeup").click();`

Comment: My aim is, hold my finger on the button.. It will keep clicking the button making the volume go up rather than clicking it once all the time? And when i release my finger (trigger touchend) it will clear the interval which keeps pressing the button at a 100 MS.

Comment: Is it working if you remove `setTimeout` related stuff? (I.e. without delay)?

Comment: You mean, use your code above but remove the `SetTimeout`?

Comment: If you mean does the button work before the timeouts etc, then yes. My code in my question works with no issue / bugs / glitches. It just doesnt `ClearInterval` on android for some strange reason.

Comment: Great Help @Annarfych Thank you so much! Will never forget the time and effort you put into this!:)